# Pairwise displacement vectors among set of points

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have an array of `N` points in `d` dimensions `(N, d)` and I'd like to make a new array of all the displacement vectors for each pair `(N choose 2, d)`.  If I just want the magnitude of these vectors, I can use [`pdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) from [`scipy.spatial.distance`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.html).

It would be great if I could just do

```py
pdist(points, lambda u, v: u - v)
```

but the `metric` function must return a scalar (`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`)

---

My solution is to use `np.triu_indices`:

```py
i, j = np.triu_indices(len(points), 1)
displacements = points[i] - points[j]
```

This is about 20-30 times slower than using `pdist` (I compare by taking the the magnitude of `displacements`, though this is not the time-consuming part, which I presume is actually making the upper triangle and running fancy indexing).

Comment: A [PR](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/4509) has just been merged into numpy master that will make this significantly faster, albeit slower than `pdist`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight forward would be

```
dis_vectors = [l - r for l, r in itertools.combinations(points, 2)]
```

but I doubt that it is fast. Actually `%timeit` says:

For 3 points:

```
list : 13 us
pdist: 24 us
```

But already for 27 points:

```
list : 798 us
pdist: 35.2 us
```

About how many points are we talking here?

Another possibility something like

```
import numpy
from operator import mul
from fractions import Fraction

def binomial_coefficient(n,k):
    # credit to http://stackoverflow.com/users/226086/nas-banov
    return int( reduce(mul, (Fraction(n-i, i+1) for i in range(k)), 1) )

def pairwise_displacements(a):
    n = a.shape[0]
    d = a.shape[1]
    c = binomial_coefficient(n, 2)

    out = numpy.zeros( (c, d) )

    l = 0
    r = l + n - 1
    for sl in range(1, n): # no point1 - point1!
        out[l:r] = a[:n-sl] - a[sl:]
        l = r
        r += n - (sl + 1)
    return out
```

This simply "slides" the array against itself over all dimensions and performs a (broadcastable) subtraction in each step. Note that no repetition is considered and no equal pairs (e.g. point1 - point1).

This function still performs well in the 1000 points range with `31.3ms`, whereas `pdist` is still faster with `20.7 ms` and the list comprehension takes the third place with `1.23 s`.

Comment: Thanks!  I usually have order 1000 points.  Also, nice implementation of choose, but `from scipy.special import binom` or `from scipy.misc import comb` would both work.

Comment: Quite right, haven't though about scipy. Maybe you can also find a more fancy way to compute the `l` and `r` indices ... I spent 15 min just looking at them but couldn't come up with anything better than incremental :)

Comment: Incremental is still faster than my solution or @Jaime's.  Also, for binomial coefficient, we always have `k=2`, so it's just `n*(n-1)/2`

Answer (score 1):

If you compute the full cartesian product of differences, flatten the resulting 2D array, and create your own indices to extract the upper triangle, you can get it to be "only" 6x slower than `pdist`:

```
In [39]: points = np.random.rand(1000, 2)

In [40]: %timeit pdist(points)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.81 ms per loop

In [41]: %%timeit
    ...: n = len(points)
    ...: rng = np.arange(1, n)
    ...: idx = np.arange(n *(n-1) // 2) + np.repeat(np.cumsum(rng), rng[::-1])
    ...: np.take((points[:, None] - points).reshape(-1, 2), idx, axis=0)
    ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 33.9 ms per loop
```

You can also speed up your solution, creating the indices yourself, and using take instead of fancy indexing:

```
In [75]: %%timeit
    ...: n = len(points)
    ...: rng = np.arange(1, n)
    ...: idx1 = np.repeat(rng - 1, rng[::-1])
    ...: idx2 = np.arange(n*(n-1)//2) + np.repeat(n - np.cumsum(rng[::-1]), rng[::-1])
    ...: np.take(points, idx1, axis=0) - np.take(points, idx2, axis=0)
    ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 38.8 ms per loop
```