# Multiply number of distances in distance matrix prior to histogram binning

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, histogram

I am using scipy.spatial.distance.pdist to calculate the distances from an array of coordinates followed by numpy.histogram to bin the results. Currently this treats each coordinate as though one object were there, however I have multiple objects at that same coordinate. One option is to change the arrays so that each coordinate occurs multiple times, once for each object at that coordinate, however this would substantially increase the size of the array and the time of calculation for pdist, since it scales as N^2, and this is prohibitively costly and speed is important in this application.

A second approach would be to treat the resulting distance matrix such that each distance is repeated ni*nj times, where ni is the number of objects at coordinate i and nj the number of objects at coordinate j. This would transform the original MxM distance matrix to be a NxN distance matrix, where M is the total number of coordinates in the array, but N is the total number of objects. But again, this seems to be unnecessarily costly since all I really need to do is somehow tell the histogramming function to multiply the number of events at distance ij by ni*nj. In other words, is there any way to tell numpy.histogram that there's not just one object at distance ij, but that there's ni*nj objects instead?

Other ideas are obviously welcome.

Edit:

This is an example of the first approach.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import spatial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#create array of 5 coordinates in 3D
coords = np.random.random(15).reshape(5,3)
'''array([[ 0.66500534,  0.10145476,  0.92528492],
       [ 0.52677892,  0.07756804,  0.50976737],
       [ 0.50030508,  0.37635556,  0.20828815],
       [ 0.02707651,  0.21878467,  0.55855427],
       [ 0.81564621,  0.82750694,  0.53083443]])'''

#number of objects at each coordinate
objects = np.random.randint(1,10,5)
#array([5, 3, 8, 5, 1])

#create new array with coordinates for each individual object
new_coords = np.zeros((objects.sum(),3))

#there's surely a simpler way to do this
j=0
for coord in range(coords.shape[0]):
    for i in range(objects[coord]):
            new_coords[j] = coords[coord]
            j+=1

'''new_coords
array([[ 0.66500534,  0.10145476,  0.92528492],
       [ 0.66500534,  0.10145476,  0.92528492],
       [ 0.66500534,  0.10145476,  0.92528492],
       [ 0.66500534,  0.10145476,  0.92528492],
       [ 0.66500534,  0.10145476,  0.92528492],
       [ 0.52677892,  0.07756804,  0.50976737],
       [ 0.52677892,  0.07756804,  0.50976737],
       [ 0.52677892,  0.07756804,  0.50976737],
       [ 0.50030508,  0.37635556,  0.20828815],
       [ 0.50030508,  0.37635556,  0.20828815],
       [ 0.50030508,  0.37635556,  0.20828815],
       [ 0.50030508,  0.37635556,  0.20828815],
       [ 0.50030508,  0.37635556,  0.20828815],
       [ 0.50030508,  0.37635556,  0.20828815],
       [ 0.50030508,  0.37635556,  0.20828815],
       [ 0.50030508,  0.37635556,  0.20828815],
       [ 0.02707651,  0.21878467,  0.55855427],
       [ 0.02707651,  0.21878467,  0.55855427],
       [ 0.02707651,  0.21878467,  0.55855427],
       [ 0.02707651,  0.21878467,  0.55855427],
       [ 0.02707651,  0.21878467,  0.55855427],
       [ 0.81564621,  0.82750694,  0.53083443]])''' 

#calculate distance matrix of old and new arrays
distances_old = distance.pdist(coords)
distances_new = distance.pdist(new_coords)

#calculate and plot normalized histograms (typically just use np.histogram without plotting)
plt.hist(distances_old, range=(0,1), alpha=.5, normed=True)
(array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.]), array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9,  1. ]), <a list of 10 Patch objects>)

plt.hist(distances_new, range=(0,1), alpha=.5, normed=True)
(array([ 2.20779221,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.68831169,
        0.64935065,  2.07792208,  2.81385281,  0.34632035,  0.21645022]), array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9,  1. ]), <a list of 10 Patch objects>)

plt.show()
```

[image: histograms]

The second approach would instead treat the distance matrix rather than the coordinate matrix, but I haven't figured that code out yet.

Both approaches seem inefficient to me and I think manipulating the binning process of np.histogram is more likely to be efficient, since it's just basic multiplication, but I'm not sure how to tell np.histogram to treat each coordinate as having a variable number of objects to count.

Comment: What is the question? Instead of describing your existing code with words, can you describe it with (copy-paste-runnable) code?

Comment: How do you know how many objects are at each location? If you have an array of counts of the same shape as the array of locations, you can pretty easily weight the histogram with that.

Comment: See my edit (y'all are quick). Yes, the object count array is the same shape as the array of coordinates.

Comment: @MrE, I think the question is pretty clear, and the edit shows an example of code.

Comment: @askewchan yes it's much better now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance

positions = np.random.rand(10, 2)
counts = np.random.randint(1, 5, len(positions))

distances = distance.pdist(positions)
i, j = np.triu_indices(len(positions), 1)

bins = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
h, b = np.histogram(distances, bins=bins, weights=counts[i]*counts[j])
```

It checks out compared to repeating, excepting the `0`-distances:

```
repeated = np.repeat(positions, counts, 0)
rdistances_r = distance.pdist(repeated)

hr, br = np.histogram(rdistances, bins=bins)

In [83]: h
Out[83]: array([11, 22, 27, 43, 67, 46, 40,  0, 19,  0])

In [84]: hr
Out[84]: array([36, 22, 27, 43, 67, 46, 40,  0, 19,  0])
```

Comment: Ahh yes, weighting. So simple. Thanks!

Comment: is there a faster way to implement both np.triu_indices or np.histogram? I find they are both the bottleneck in my code. I have "positions" arrays that contain thousands of coordinates and this is proving to be too slow (~10+ seconds) for my needs (tenths of seconds) I would have thought that pdist would be the bottleneck, but it's not.  For a 10,000 coordinate array pdist only takes ~0.8 seconds (slow, but borderline acceptable), but indices takes ~8 seconds and histogram takes about 5 seconds, which is too long. Any thoughts?

Comment: I used `triu_indices` because it's the easiest to understand, but there are faster ways to generate that.  Take a look at some of the discussion at a recent question of mine: [Pairwise displacement vectors among set of points](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22390418/1730674).  I don't think you can speed up `histogram` though, I think it's already as fast as it can easily get, but you could search elsewhere or ask another question.